# Can anyone tell the meaning of this word "sea late"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the original sentence

> He passed by finishing line five kilometres out to sea late on Friday.

What is the meaning of "sea late" in this sentence? I don't get it.

Comment: I think there should be a comma after "sea", also one after "line".

Comment: As a note, if it has a space, it's not a "word".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per WS2's comment. There are two elements there:

Where?

> 5 kilometres out to sea

When?

> Late on Friday